# Create an array by passing the txt file and Pass array reference variable to the heapsort method

Tags: java, file-io, data-structures, heapsort

I need help with my project for data structure course. I am suppose to read 10 employees data stored in a text file called Employee.txt and read them into an array then pass that array into the heapSort method and print the sorted employees into an output file called SortedEmployee.txt. For some reason my program is not working. Can anyone help please?

Class Employee

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Employee
{
    public String empId , empName , empDept , empPos;
    public double empSalary;
    public int empServ;

Employee()
{
  empId = ("");
  empName = (""); 
  empDept = (""); 
  empPos = ("");
  empSalary = 0.0;
  empServ = 0;
}
Employee(String id ,String name, double salary, String dept , String pos, int serv)
{
  empId = id;
  empName = name;
  empDept = dept;
  empPos = pos;
  empSalary = salary;
  empServ = serv;
}
public void setId(String id)
{
  empId = id;
}           
public void setName(String name)
{
  empName = name;
}
public void setDept(String dept)
{
  empDept = dept;
} 
public void setPos(String pos)
{
  empPos = pos;
}
public void setSalary(double salary)
{
  empSalary = salary;
}
public void setServ(int serv)
{
  empServ = serv;
}       
public String getId()
{
  return empId;
}
public String getName()
{
  return empName;
}
public String getDept()
{
  return empDept;
}
public String getPos()
{
  return empPos;
}
public double getSalary()
{
  return empSalary;
}
public int getServ()
{
  return empServ;
}
public String toString()
{
  String str = "Employee Name : " + empName + "\nEmployee ID : " + empId +
                 "\nEmployee Deaprtment : " + empDept + "\nEmployee Position : " 
                 + empPos + "\nEmployee Salary : " + empSalary 
                 + "\nEmployee Years   Served : " + empServ;
  return str;
}
public int compareTo(Employee emp)
{
  int id = empId.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.empId);
  if (id != 0)
     return id;
  return 0;
}                  
}
```

Class HeapSort

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;

class zNode
{
   private int iData;             

public zNode(int key)           
{ 
  iData = key; 
}
public int getKey()
{ 
  return iData; 
}
public void setKey(int k)
{
  iData = k; 
}
} 


class HeapSort
{
   private int [] currArray;
   private int maxSize;          
   private int currentSize;
   private int currIndex;

HeapSort(int mx)            
{
  maxSize = mx;
  currentSize = 0;
  currArray = new int[maxSize];  
}

//buildheap
public boolean buildHeap(int [] currArray)
{
  int key = currIndex;
  if(currentSize==maxSize)
     return false;
  int newNode = key;
  currArray[currentSize] = newNode;
  siftUp(currArray , currentSize++);
  return true;
}

//siftup
public void siftUp(int [] currArray , int currIndex)
{
  int parent = (currIndex-1) / 2;
  int bottom = currArray[currIndex];

  while( currIndex > 0 && currArray[parent] < bottom )
  {
     currArray[currIndex] = currArray[parent];  
     currIndex = parent;
     parent = (parent-1) / 2;
  }  
  currArray[currIndex] = bottom;
 }

//siftdown
public void siftDown(int [] currArray , int currIndex)
{
  int largerChild;
  int top = currArray[currIndex];       
  while(currIndex < currentSize/2)       
  {                               
     int leftChild = 2*currIndex+1;
     int rightChild = leftChild+1;

     if(rightChild < currentSize && currArray[leftChild] < currArray[rightChild] )
        largerChild = rightChild;
     else
        largerChild = leftChild;

     if( top >= currArray[largerChild] )
        break;

     currArray[currIndex] = currArray[largerChild];
     currIndex = largerChild;            
   }  
   currArray[currIndex] = top;            
   }

//remove max element
public int removeMaxElement(int [] currArray)          
{                           
  int root = currArray[0];
  currArray[0] = currArray[--currentSize];
  siftDown(currArray , 0);
  return root;
}  

//heapsort
private void _sortHeapArray(int [] currArray)
{
  while(currentSize != 0)
  {
     removeMaxElement(currArray);
  }
}

public void sortHeapArray()
{
  _sortHeapArray(currArray);
} 

//hepify
private int[] heapify(int[] currArray) 
{
  int start = (currentSize) / 2;
  while (start >= 0) 
  {
     siftDown(currArray, start);
     start--;
  }
  return currArray;
}

//swap
private int[] swap(int[] currArray, int index1, int index2) 
{
  int swap = currArray[index1];
  currArray[index1] = currArray[index2];
  currArray[index2] = swap;
  return currArray;
}

//heapsort
public int[] _heapSort(int[] currArray) 
{
  heapify(currArray);
  int end = currentSize-1;
  while (end > 0) 
  {
     currArray = swap(currArray,0, end);
     end--;
     siftDown(currArray, end);
  }
  return currArray;
}
public void heapSort()
{  
  _heapSort(currArray);

}   

//main method
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
{
    HeapSort mySort = new HeapSort(10);
    Employee [] myArray = new Employee[10];

    String firstFile = ("Employee.txt");
    FileReader file = new FileReader(firstFile); 
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);   

    String secondFile = ("SortedEmployee.txt");
    PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter(secondFile);

    String[] currArray = new String[10];
String lineContent;
    while ((lineContent = br.readLine()) != null)
    {    
    for (int i = 0; i < currArray.length; i++)
    {
           lineContent = br.readLine();
           currArray[i] = String.valueOf(lineContent);
           mySort.heapSort(); 
           outputFile.println(mySort);
           }
         }         
    outputFile.close();
    System.out.print("Done");

     } 
    }
```

I know that the problem is in the main method in the while loop but I just don't know how to solve it.

Employee.txt:

```
086244

Sally L. Smith

100000.00

Accounting

Manager

7

096586

Meredith T. Grey

150000.00

Physical Therapy

Doctor

9

875236

Christina R. Yang

190000.00

Cardiology

Resident

10

265893

George A. O'Malley

98000.00

Pediatrics

Attending

7
etc......
```

Comment: What is not working for you?

Comment: It is not sorting.. I need it to sort by Id's using heapsort.

Comment: Firsr of all, try sorting it with "Bubble Sort", then "Selection Sort"... just to see that all algorithms are compatible. Then aim for the bgigger picture. (This is in order to see that your base is correct.)

Answer (score 1):

You have not implemented `Comparable<Employee>`. It should like this.

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee emp){
       return this.empId.compareToIgnoreCase(emp.empId);
    }
}
```

Simply use [Arrays.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) method to sort an array.

Comment: @ambigram_maker how? explain a bit more.

Comment: While a hard working fellow spends day-in and day-out to _write his own code_ the [programmer] displays his resourcefulness :-)

Comment: We have specific instructions for this project so I cannot use any other sorting method. I have to use heapSort. My question is what should i be passing into my sort method? the Employee myArray or the String currArray?

Comment: @user3516473 Why have you created a method `compareTo()` in `Employee` class?

Comment: @user3516473 you are sorting `int[]` rather than `Employee[]` that's incorrect.

Comment: I dont necessarily need it. I just have it in case I need it.